# Scraping box ccores with BeautifulSoup and using pandas to export to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to figure out how to scrape baseball box scores from Fangraphs with Python 3.6 and the BeautifulSoup and Pandas modules. My final goal is to save different sections of the webpage to different sheets in Excel.

In order to do this, I think I have to pull each table separately by their respective id tags. This is the code to do so for the four tables (below the graph on the page) that would make up the first excel sheet. Running the code results in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Fangraphs Box Score Scraper.py", line 14, in <module>
df1 = pd.read_html(soup,attrs={'id': ['WinsBox1_dghb','WinsBox1_dghp','WinsBox1_dgab','WinsBox1_dgap']})

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 906, in read_html
keep_default_na=keep_default_na)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 743, in _parse
raise_with_traceback(retained)

File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 344, in raise_with_traceback

raise exc.with_traceback(traceback)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/boxscore.aspx?date=2017-09-10&team=Red%20Sox&dh=0&season=2017'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

df1 = pd.read_html(soup,attrs={'id': ['WinsBox1_dghb','WinsBox1_dghp','WinsBox1_dgab','WinsBox1_dgap']})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Box Scores.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Traditional Box Scores')
```

Comment: please, add full error stack

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use wrong `id`, you take it form `<div>` but need take from `<table>` tags [read_html attrs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) and i think you do not need to use bs, try it:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.fangraphs.com/boxscore.aspx?date=2017-09-10&team=Red%20Sox&dh=0&season=2017'
df1 = pd.read_html(
    url,
    attrs={'id': ['WinsBox1_dghb_ctl00', 'WinsBox1_dgab_ctl00']}
)

# and now df1 it is list of df
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Box Scores.xlsx')
row = 0
for df in df1:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='tables', startrow=row , startcol=0)   
    row = row + len(df.index) + 3

writer.save()
```

Comment: glad to help you, please, don forget to accept the answer